# MVC custom error pages work in dev but not in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created some custom error pages in a MVC4 project. I use Application_Error and also the HandleErrorAttribute for routing.

Also,

It works fine in my dev computer, under IIS 8.0

When I publish the project to the production server, under IIS 7.5, it shows the default error pages, not custom pages.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your custom errors mode? (i.e. <customErrors mode="Off" /> in web.config)

Comment: <customErrors mode="On" />. In any case, I do not recompile the project. I simply copy it from my dev PC to production.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error.html" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error redirect="~/Error/403.aspx" statusCode="403" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/404.aspx" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/500.html" statusCode="500" />
    </customErrors>
```

Create page 403.aspx in root directory "Error"

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>403 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    Server.ClearError();
Response.Status = "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.";
Response.StatusCode = 403;
         %>
    <div>
    <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any response code setting statement from the action method.

Like

```
 Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

Remove it and give a try.